# ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras

ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import numpy as np


(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

X_train1 = X_train.copy().ravel()
y_train1 = y_train.copy().ravel()

X_train2 = X_train1.resize(64*64*500)
y_train2 = y_train1.resize(64*64*500)

X_train = X_train2.resize(64*64*500).reshape(64, 64, 1)
y_train = y_train2.resize(64*64*500).reshape(64, 64, 1)
```

Why am I getting this error after explicitly copying the data ? How to fix this ?

Comment: Did you read the docs for `np.resize` and for the `resize` method?  They are different.  Also which `resize` is giving the problem?  Why are you using `resize` at all?   What's the shape of `X_train`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using reshape in numpy, Change lines to

```
X_train2 = np.resize(X_train1, 64*64*500)
y_train2 = np.resize(y_train1, 64*64*500)
```